# Django storing mobile number, what field to use?

Tags: django, django-models

In my models I need to store a mobile number in the following format 447182716281. What field should I use? Does Django have anything to support this?

example

```
 mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is a interesting question since it really depends on the problem modeling, CharField works fine, but have a look at this:

[ORM tricks](https://speakerdeck.com/jacobian/stupid-orm-tricks)

Answer (score 5):

Phone numbers must be CharFields. Integer field will not preserve leading 0, +, and spacing.

Comment: does it support some sort of regex then, because a CharFields is very general.

Comment: Why do you need the plus sign? Can you use PhoneNumberField() without it?

Comment: I like this approach. Makes it simple

Answer (score 3):

There is a regex field in form validation. In model use just CharField.

Answer (score 2):

On using models.IntegerField(default=0)
for larger number it gives error 
Ensure this value is less than or equal to 2147483647.

So better way to use would be.
BigIntegerField
A 64-bit integer, much like an IntegerField except that it is guaranteed to fit numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The default form widget for this field is a TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

with PostgreSQL IntegerField is not working properly so it's better to use CharField with Django.

```
Number=models.CharField(max_length=12)
```